# the run/debug/device selection in android studio are grayed out

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

for context i'm new to android studio

so basically i wanted to learn flutter, so i installed it and installed android studio as well

but after i configured everything (SDK path and environment variables included) it still won't run any apps and the whole area is grayed out as you can see in the image i linked.
i have tried to make sure that my sdk is correct and that my flutter permessions are all allowed.
i also tried reinstalling the whole thing but nothing happened.

[android studio run bar gray and wont work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37GZF.png)

Comment: run "flutter doctor"  command in terminal and check anything missing

Comment: i already did that and everything is fine

Comment: Go to the project directory and enter command "flutter run"

Comment: it gives me this problem after running flutter doctor again


flutter requires android sdk 29 and the android buildtools 28.0.3 to update the android sdk visit...


i dont uderstand i have everything set up as its supposed to..

Comment: so i tried updating sdk to the version it says and now flutter doctor finds no problems but i still cant run the app

Answer (score 0):

okay guys i fixed it thank you all for the help

for any future readers, hi from past :D

i went into the plugin sections in the settings and made sure all my installed plugins were up to date

i then installed the flutter plugin and restarted the IDE. Fixed everything.